# How to prove there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ such that $\sum^\infty_{k=1} a_{n_k}$ converges in the following situation?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $\lim\inf |a_n|=0$. How to prove there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ such that $\sum^\infty_{k=1} a_{n_k}$ converges?

By the definition of cauchy criterion,  I think what we want is $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N$ such that $n\ge m\gt N\implies |\sum^n_{k=m} a_k|<\epsilon$. Now assume $\lim\inf |a_n|=0$, then by deifinition of $\inf$, we know $\forall t<0, \exists N, \forall n>N, |a_n|>t$. Let $\epsilon>0, t=-\epsilon$, then $t<0$, since $|a_n|>t\implies a_n<-t=\epsilon$, we can also say $n>N\implies a_{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{n-m+1}$ where $n\ge m>N$, then we have $|\sum^n_{k=m} a_k|=|a_m+a_{m+1}+...+a_n|<|\frac{(n-m+1)\epsilon}{n-m+1}|=\epsilon$. Since $\sum^\infty_{k=1} a_{n}$ converges, it has subsequence converge to same limit.

However I feel the proof is not rigorous and has errors. Could someone fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\liminf |a_n| = 0$, for every $k\in\mathbb N$, the number $1/2^k$ is not a lower bound of the set $\{a_n\}$. Hence there is an $n_k$ such that $|a_{n_k}| < 1/2^k$. By comparison, $\sum_k |a_{n_k}|\le \sum_k 1/2^k$, so $\sum a_{n_k}$ converges absolutely, and hence in the usual sense.

To make it a little more transparent, we can construct $(a_{n_k})$ inductively as follows. Since $1/2$ is not a lower bound for $(|a_n|)$, there is some $n_1$ such that $|a_{n_1}|<1/2$. Let $n_2>n_1$ be the first index such that $|a_{n_2}|<1/4$, which exists as $\liminf |a_n| = 0$. Let $n_3 > n_2$ be the first index such that $|a_{n_3}| < 1/8$, which exists as $\liminf |a_n| = 0$. Proceed inductively.

Comment: +1. Perhaps you should mention how to construct the $(n_k)$ so that it's increasing.

Comment: Can we pick $\frac{1}{k^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2^k}$?

Comment: @CoolKid Sure, any sequence works because we are just applying the property of the $\liminf$ repeatedly.

Comment: Since we are applying the comparison test, is it necessary to construct an increasing $a_{n_k}$?

Comment: @CoolKid The sum $\sum_k|a_{n_k}|$ is independent of whether $a_{n_k}$ appears before $a_{n_\ell}$ for $k < \ell$ in the original sequence $(a_n)$, but we are asked to demonstrate the existence of a *subsequence*, which requires that we produce an increasing sequence $n_1<n_2<n_3<\dots$ for our subsequence.